# How to measure time-dependant inhomogenity?

Tags: time-series, correlation

At t = 0 my two variables x und y do not correlate. Due to an event, at t = 1 x und y suddenly correlate....
Is there a way to measure the the disorder of the two variables at t = 0, so that I can say that due to the specific event, the data becomes more "ordered". Something like skewness, entropy, ...?